# Laravel Form Builder datetime input

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, formbuilder

Is there a Laravel 5 Form Builder equivalent of HTML 5's datatime input field ? I have been searching all day but could not find any.

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="game-date-time-text" name="game_date_time">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to see this package: https://github.com/Braunson/laravel-html5-forms

Answer (score 7):

That worked

```
{{ Form::input('dateTime-local', 'game_date_time', $game->game_date_time, ['id' => 'game-date-time-text', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
```